# Bandwidth Issues with Fluid Widths for Images

Tags: css, html

OK, I get the whole fluid width thing. Very cool. But what about bandwidth? Esp. for Mobile.

Consider...

1. Assume I have a photo website that is showing this picture: http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/4321052153/sizes/l/in/photostream/
2. The size of this beautiful behemoth is **847kb**
3. Yes, I can use size=100%, and it will scale...**BUT**...the file **is STILL 847kb!**
4. Size works in mobile, ***but a bandwidth nightmare***.

I want to scale the actual byte size of my image along with its perceived size on-screen.

I want to know if this is even **possible** with current tech. As I do not think users will appreciate an 847kb file - no matter how pretty it is. I want to know what options, if any, are available. I have searched and cannot think of a way to do this short of serving a SEPARATE image. Which is not very "responsive".

Comment: Maybe instead of "Solutions?" I should have said **"Can you think of any solutions or work-arounds for this dilemma?"** How's that?

Comment: That's better, but the question itself is still a bit vague, you want to scale the actual byte size of your image along with its perceived size on-screen? Try adding a description of what your desired outcome is :)

Comment: Yes. **"I want to scale the actual byte size of your image along with its perceived size on-screen".** I want to know if this is even _**possible**_ with current tech. As I do not think users will appreciate an 847kb file - no matter how pretty it is. I want to know what options, if any, are available. I have searched and cannot think of a way to do this short of serving a SEPARATE image. Which is not very "responsive". I hope this makes it clear.

Comment: Edited your question to include the updated question. :)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks  Thank you for helping me flesh out my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, fluid/responsive design is all about design, the aim of it is making the website looks good at various screen sizes. It does nothing for the technical aspects of website optimization.

In this case, you want to optimize not only the look (using fluid layout) but also the loading time and bandwidth. The solution would be process the image on server before transfer it to user.

Examples: http://adaptive-images.com/, http://24ways.org/2011/adaptive-images-for-responsive-designs.

Answer (score 2):

Server side, on-demand image resizing? Have a look at [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net/) project as an example. It allows you to resize an image on-demand using query string parameters. You can upload your 5MP images as is and use this library to serve scaled versions of that image to the audience. You wont need separate images any more.

I believe there are other similar solutions available.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party here, but `http://resrc.it` deliver responsive images on demand. I know they are fairly new and this question is now quite old but worth a mention should any body else be looking at repsponsive imagery.

Answer (score 0):

If JPEG2000 maintained all the promises and was fully adopted by browsers, delivering lightweight thumbnails could be automatically handled by the web server, no extra coding required (in a sort of progressive image streaming).

But this is not going to happen, so as stated above you need to store the thumbnails server-side, and deliver them on request.